# Alternative of package PathProviderEx in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter2.0

Tried every thing, when trying to access the root directory of the app it throws this exceptions.

Is there any way to get the root of device on flutter2 with null safety ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, use this package https://pub.dev/packages/external_path to get root Directory of the device.